# What's the correct way to set default values for a model at creation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, default

How should I set up my model so that the default value for a given field is set when the record is created *and* I can run validations on that field?

As an example, let's say I have a field `bar` that I want to default to 0 if no value is given when the record is created. I also want to ensure that bar isn't nil, with `validates_presence_of :bar`.

If I do this:

```
before_create :defaults
def defaults
  bar ||= 0
end
```

...then the default never works; the validations fail because bar is nil before it calls defaults.

But if I do this:

```
before_validation :defaults
def defaults
  bar ||= 0
end
```

then the default gets set before *every* validation, which makes the following produce some odd results:

```
foo = Foo.new
foo.bar = nil
foo.save!
```

Instead of raising an exception because you tried to set bar to an invalid value, the save succeeds and sets bar to 0.

I suppose I could do this:

```
before_validation :defaults
def defaults
  if new_record?
    bar ||= 0
    # set any other default values
  end
end
```

... but that seems a bit smelly, not to mention inefficient (something I only care about at creation is being called for every validation).

Is there some more elegant way I can have bar default to 0 *before* validations are checked and *only* on creation?

Comment: I wouldn't say it's very inefficient. The method exits early. And I would guess that the amount of time your code spends in `Foo#save` is negligible, compared to other work. I'd leave that as it is (for I know no better way).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's `before_validation :defaults, :on => :create`, which only gets called on create.

Comment: Ah, thanks! I hadn't realized before_validation had an `:on =>` option.